# Moving reports from sharepoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: migration, reporting-services, reports

I currently have both a sharepoint 2007 farm and a sharepoint 2010 farm, both have an SSRS server.

I need to move the reports from SP 2007 to SP 2010 and I'm not sure how to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a new SSRS Server associated with your SP 2010 Farm and you'd like to move all the reports from an old SSRS Server associated with your SP 2007 Farm. If that is the case, the easiest method maybe to move the entire SSRS Database from the old server to the new one.

There is a great TechNet article on [moving SQL Server Reporting Services databases to another server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

The basic summary is:

1. Backup the encryption keys on your SP 2007 SSRS Server
2. Detach the databases on your SP 2007 SSRS Server
3. Attach the databases on your SP 2010 SSRS Server
4. Verify the RSExecRole has select, insert, update, delete, and reference permissions on the report server database tables, and execute permissions on the stored procedures.
5. Use the Reporting Services Configuration tool to connect to the Reporting Server
6. Restore the encryption keys on your SP 2010 SSRS Server
7. Restart the Report Server service